# ¿Por qué if no asigna el nuevo valor a la variable?

Tags: php, condiciones, wordpress-plugin

Mientras realizo un plugin para Wordpress, no veo por qué no se asigna el valor a la variable $imgluna

Lo muestro con if - endif, pero ya lo intenté con if - elseif - endif

También ya lo intenté con if {} y nada

También ya lo intenté con case ()

Aquí está el código:

```
if ($a > 29):
    $lafase = $a - 29;
else: 
    $lafase = $a;
endif;


if ($fase = 1): $imgluna = 1; endif;



if ($fase = 27): $imgluna = 9; endif;
```

Comment: el if es con 2  iguales, o 3 para ir mejor y usando YodaConditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los valores no se asignan porque con `$fase` no estás usando realmente un [*operador de comparación*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php). Para igualdad existen dos operadores en PHP, este, `==` que compara solamente si los dos valores son iguales, o este `===` que compara si los dos valores son iguales y si son del mismo tipo (esto se llama también comparación estricta).

Pero, viendo tu código, creo que puedes usar *operadores ternarios*  (ver enlace de más arriba). Estos operadores son fáciles de entender, sobre todo en comparaciones simples, y ayudan mucho a simplificar el código.

Así, en vez de esto:

```
if ($a > 29):
    $lafase = $a - 29;
else: 
    $lafase = $a;
endif;
```

Podrías tener algo así, en una sola línea usando operadores ternarios:

```
$lafase= ($a > 29) ? $a - 29 : $a;
```

Simplemente evalúa la condición a la izquierda de `?`, si es verdadera la variable toma el valor a la izquierda de `:` y si es falsa el valor a la derecha de `:`

Para la otra operación, se pueden concatenar operadores ternarios, entonces esto:

```
if ($fase == 1): $imgluna = 1; endif;

if ($fase == 27): $imgluna = 9; endif;
```

Se haría así:

```
#Asumiremos que `0` es el valor por defecto por eso es el último valor que se asigna
$imgluna = ($fase == 1) ? 1 : (($fase == 27)  ? 9 : 0);
```

Si `$imgluna` es una variable que ya existe y debe permanecer invariable si ninguna de las condiciones se cumplen:

```
$imgluna = ($fase == 1) ? 1 : (($fase == 27)  ? 9 : $imgluna);
```

### Otra posibilidad

Sobre todo cuando hay muchos `if` o bloques `switch ... case` grandes, se puede usar datos estructurados en arrays y buscar allí los valores.

El array pondría en relación el valor que se debe tomar en cada caso, por ejemplo:

```
$allImg=array(
                "1"=>1,
                "27"=>9,
                # Más opciones 
              );
$fase=27;
#Se usa un ternario y se asigna 0 por defecto
$imgluna= isset($allImg[$fase]) ? $allImg[$fase] : 0;
echo $imgluna;
```

Si hay una nueva opción, no tienes que modificar nada, solamente agregarla en el array `$allImg`, y el código hará el resto. Es genial, ¿no?

**Salida:**

```
9
```

Comment: Mil gracias por tu pronta respuesta y sobre todo acertada, con esto se resuelve el problema

Comment: @LuisMoreno Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

No estas haciendo una comparación dentro del if sino una asignación a $fase. Las comparaciones son con `==`

Prueba así

```
if ($fase == 1): $imgluna = 1; endif;

if ($fase == 27): $imgluna = 9; endif;
```

Comment: Correcto, con eso bastó. Saludos